# Angular service written in typescript is undefined inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am implementing a simple angular application with typescript. 
I pass a service reference to a controller, but when I try to invoke a service's method I get an exception saying the service reference is undefined. The "dataAccessLayer" module is correctly added as dependency in "clinicManager" module (the one to which the controller belongs)

**My service:**

```
module app.dal{

interface IDataAccessService{
    get(id:number):app.Model.IPatient;
}

export class DataAccessService implements IDataAccessService{
    private _db : Loki;

    static $inject = ['Loki'];
    constructor(private Loki:Loki) {
        this._db = new Loki('./database/db.json',{
            autosave: true,
            autosaveInterval : 3000 // 3 secs
        });
    }

    get(id:number):app.Model.IPatient {

          // Implementation here...
        }
    }

angular.module('dataAccessLayer',['lokijs'])
    .service('dataAccessService',['Loki',DataAccessService]);
}
```

**The controller:**

```
module app.PatientDetails{

interface IPatientDetails{
    patient: app.Model.IPatient;
}

import accessLayer = app.dal.DataAccessService;

export class PatientDetailsCtrl implements IPatientDetails{

    private dataAccessService: accessLayer;

    static $inject = ['patient','dataAccessService'];
    constructor(public patient:app.Model.IPatient, dataAccessService:accessLayer){
        this.dataAccessService = dataAccessService;

        // -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
        var patient = dataAccessService.get(1);

    }
}

  angular.module('clinicManager')
         .controller('patientDetailsCtrl',['dataAccessService',PatientDetailsCtrl]);
 }
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('clinicManager',['ngMaterial','dataAccessLayer']);
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- Application scripts-->
<script src="app.js"></script>

<!-- Services-->
<script src="DataAccessLayer/DataAccessService.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers-->
<script src="Controllers/PatientDetailsCtrl.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is order of your scripts correct?

Comment: I updated the request with the scripts order. To my eyes the order is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service gets properly instantiated if I remove the reference to Patient in the controller, the service works fine. I put the code here to better show the formatting:

```
module app.PatientDetails{

interface IPatientDetails{
     // patient: app.Model.IPatient;
 }

import accessLayer = app.dal.DataAccessService;

export class PatientDetailsCtrl implements IPatientDetails{

    private dataAccessService: accessLayer;

    static $inject = [/*'patient',*/'dataAccessService'];
    constructor(/*public patient:app.Model.IPatient,*/ dataAccessService:accessLayer){
        this.dataAccessService = dataAccessService;

    // The function is now called properly
    var patient = dataAccessService.get(1);

   }
}

  angular.module('clinicManager')
         .controller('patientDetailsCtrl', ['dataAccessService',PatientDetailsCtrl]);
}
```